# Javascript date filter improving

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/zxAc4/)

I wrote javascript/jquery UI which filters a list of items by date.

One `<li class="list-group-item listItem" id="0001">` - for one item.

Each `<input type="hidden" id="01_0001" class="form-control dateItem dataField_0001" value="11/23/2012">` for each item date.

Task was to show item if at least one of it's dates is in scope of datepicker.
If there is no dates for one item - it needs to be hidden.

SO, everything works well, but it is very slow.

There are around 300 items and more then 2000 dates and when my script parsing data it takes more then 30 seconds.

Question: is there any way to optimize my code or should I use anything else for this task?

Please, see fiddle in the beginning of post.

Best regards, 
Alex

```
/* Create dates +/- 7 for each "from" and "to" fields */
    var prevWeek = new Date();
        prevWeek.setDate( prevWeek.getDate() - 7 );
    var prevMonth = ( prevWeek.getMonth() + 1 );
    var prevDay =  prevWeek.getDate();
    var prevYear = prevWeek.getFullYear();
    var prevWeekDate = (( prevMonth < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + prevMonth + "/" + (prevDay < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + prevDay + "/" + prevYear );
    /*console.log('prevWeekDate =' + prevWeekDate);*/

    var nextWeek = new Date();
        nextWeek.setDate( nextWeek.getDate() + 7 );
    var nextMonth = ( nextWeek.getMonth() + 1 );
    var nextDay = nextWeek.getDate();
    var nextYear = nextWeek.getFullYear();
    var nextWeekDate = (( nextMonth < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + nextMonth + "/" + ( nextDay < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + nextDay + "/" + nextYear );
    /*console.log('nextWeekDate =' + nextWeekDate); */


/*function - datepicker setup*/
    $(function() {

        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "-1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                //console.log (selectedDate);
                filterDates();
        } });

        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                //console.log (selectedDate);
                filterDates();
        } });
    });

/*parse date string to array*/
    function dateToArray(date) {
        var dateArray = date.split('/');
        return dateArray;
    }


        function filterDates() {

            var from = dateToArray($('#from').val());
            //console.log (from);
            var from = new Date(parseInt(from[2], 10),
                                parseInt(from[0], 10) - 1,
                                parseInt(from[1], 10));
            //console.log (from);

            var to = dateToArray($('#to').val());
            //console.log (to);
            var to = new Date(  parseInt(to[2], 10),
                                parseInt(to[0], 10) - 1,
                                parseInt(to[1], 10));
            //console.log (to);

            $( '.block').each( function() {
                var itemId = $(this).attr('class');
                var itemId = itemId.split('_');
                var itemId = itemId[1];
                var displayBlock = false;

                $('.dataField_'+ itemId).each( function () {
                    var inputValue = $(this).attr('value');
                    var inputId = $(this).attr('id');

                    //console.log (inputValue + ' ' +inputId);

                    var testField = ($(this).attr( 'value' )).split('/');
                    console.log (testField);
                    var testField = new Date(   parseInt(testField[2], 10),
                                                parseInt(testField[0], 10) - 1,
                                                parseInt(testField[1], 10));
                    // console.log (testField);

                    var result = (testField < from || testField > to);

                    if (!result) { displayBlock = true; }

                });

                if (displayBlock) {
                    $('.listItem#' + itemId).removeClass('hideItem');
                } else {
                    $('.listItem#' + itemId).addClass('hideItem'); 
                }
            })
        } 

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#checkAllBox").click(function() {
            if ($("#checkAllBox").prop('checked')) {
                $(".checkBoxItem").prop( "checked", true );
            } else {
                $(".checkBoxItem").prop( "checked", false );
            }
        });

    $("#from").val(prevWeekDate);
    $("#to").val(nextWeekDate);


        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            position:['middle',120],
        });

        $( ".startDialog").click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

        filterDates();

        $('.listItem').click(function(){
            var itemId = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log (itemId);            
        });
    })
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a link to the fiddle.

Comment: one rule of thumb is if you find $(this) more than once within a function, cache the object to cut down on extra function call to create a new jQuery object that you already created and threw away. Same with any repeated selectors  `var $this= $(this)`... `$this.doSomething()` ..also....  `this.id & this.value` are much faster than `attr()` since they are native properties. These won't be huge improvements to your code but eery bit helps

Comment: Thanks on this point. I'll learn more about caching.

Answer (score 1):

First idea that comes to mind is to keep the dates as iso timestamps, and get rid of the Date parsing. So you will have an isoDate attribute for each input, looking like "20130101", instead of "01/01/2013". The input boxes that select the boundaries will also return timestamps like this. Then you will be able to compare raw strings. Try this and let us know if the speed picks up.

And another idea: You could have an array somewhere in the page containing objects with two properties: the iso timestamp and a reference to the dom node associated to the timestamp ( the node that needs to be hidden). The array will be sorted by timestamp, so a lot easier to filter based on boundaries. Having pre-populated references to dom nodes will also mean you will not need to look for them through the dom every time.

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to make input data in a format JavaScript may use without parsing it into array. Good point, thanks.